# Apple Holiday Calendar for Vietnam

Tags: icloud, calendar, ical

Apple used to maintain its own [set of calendars](http://www.apple.com/ical/library/), but that page no longer exists, and recently my subscription for Vietnamese holidays (pulled from Apple’s now-retired page) stopped updating in the Calendar app.

It’s easy enough to derive certain countries’ holiday subscriptions from the [US one](https://p20-calendars.icloud.com/holiday/US_en.ics). For instance you can subscribe to French holidays at https://p20-calendars.icloud.com/holiday/FR_fr.ics. However there doesn’t seem to be one at https://p20-calendars.icloud.com/holiday/VN_vn.ics.

Does anyone have the address for Apple’s Vietnamese holiday calendar? I realize there may be other sites that offer such calendars, but I’d prefer to use Apple’s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, Apple had made it so that you have to change your region in Language and Region Preferences in Settings to Vietnam. Also, you need to add the regional language as well to see the holidays of that region, but you don't need to make it the primary language. [View here for more information.](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205367)

There isn't a link for apple's calendar subscription, so the easiest is to just use another calendar for Vietnamese holidays: [Vietnamese Calendar.](https://www.calendarlabs.com/ical-calendar/holidays/vietnam-holidays-77/)

Hope this helps ;D

Comment: Well, I guess that’s the reason there isn’t a calendar at https://p20-calendars.icloud.com/holiday/VN_vn.ics: Apple simply removed the Vietnamese holidays calendar. I made a guest account and set its region to Vietnam, and no new calendar would show up in **Calendar** after disabling/enabling *Show Holidays calendar*.